# Can I use Convolution Neural Network (CNN) as a two class classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I have *two class data sets*. I want to **classify them using  Convolution Neural Network**. So Is it possible? Is there any build in functions available. I don't have any idea about CNN so any kind of help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? I don't see any neural network (or any other machine learning classification technique) unable to classify two classes... You'll just need to adjust your output neutrons accordingly. I think this question can be improved once you read more about neural network.